# Vim syntax highlighting not working

Tags: vim

Tried following these instructions https://github.com/sickill/vim-monokai.

My /usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/ directory contains monokai.vim. If I use vim on files in there, words are different colors. Yet when I use vim on textfiles in ~/Documents/ the background is grey but there's no different colors highlighting words, all text is white.

The output of the following when I input it into my terminal

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

is as follows

```
syntax enable
set nu
colorscheme monokai
```

Comment: What types of files are you opening in ~/Documents?

Comment: What about "set ft?" ?

Comment: Don't do anything in `/usr/share/vim/`. The right location for your colorscheme is `~/.vim/colors/monokai.vim`. Also, use `syntax on`, not `syntax enable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mkasberg hit the issue, I was opening plain text files rather than files with extensions like .c .